# WordPress query shows no posts

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I use the ACF plugin and I create a page with a date picker for a start and end date.

Now I want to show all posts between these dates, but it doesn't work. My code looks something like this:

```
$start = get_field('start', 124);
$end = get_field('end', 124);

$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            //'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'     => $start,
            'before'    => $end,
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Does someone know what's wrong? Thanks for your help.
The form of the date is always F j, Y.

Comment: What the heck is 124? Query posts based on date (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) seems like what you should be doing.

Comment: 124 ist the id of the page (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/). And I think your solution requires a start and enddate for every post. But only the page contains the date pickers.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be loading in the ID of the page if you're already on the page. Really, to do this properly you would put the start/end date on the post itself. Otherwise, if you want to show all posts between the dates, then you would be using the WP post data for publish date... not ACF. The only way I'd see to use ACF is to see if the WP post data falls between.